# Multiple directory zip archive

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

Below `script` is working when `start_dir` contains single directory path like (/root/Inbound). When I'm doing further extension `start_dir=(/root/Inbound /root/Outbound)` to point the multiple directory it's not working and it's taking zip file only first path `/root/Inbound`.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_dir=(/root/Inbound /root/Outbound)

echo "start_dir=$start_dir"

for d in "$start_dir"/*/ ; do
   cd "$d" || exit
   dirs=(*/)
   declare -p dirs
   echo "Entring into location"
   for sub_dir in "${dirs[@]}"
   do
     echo "$sub_dir"
     zip -r "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"
   done
done
```

Comment: `for d in "${start_dir[@]}"/*/ ; do` maybe...

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Hi @ Jetchisel, Thanks for the input its working perfectly.